# Reasons that exp_send truncates commands

Tags: tcl, expect

I have an infrastructure that uses Expect to interact with multiple PCs (some are Windows 7 [via cygwin], others are Ubuntu 12).

Sometimes, the expect command hangs until a timeout is reached.
Then, I noticed that not all of the command has been sent to the destination PC - the string that I sent with `exp_send` is being arbitrarily truncated.

For example, if the prompt string is `root@myPC:/#` and the command is `echo "Hello World!"`, then in `expect_out(buffer)` I may see something like this:

```
echo "Hroot@myPC:/#
```

*I verified that the command hasn't been executed in the destination PC.*

Do you know what are the possible reasons for this to happen?
Also, would it be possible to prevent this?

The Expect script is executed as part of a Tcl 8.5 script.

---

**Edit #1, 11.02.2014 15:04 UTC:**

See [this debug output of expect](http://pastebin.com/M82rBzyu) (trimmed for readability).

You can see that `exp_send` sends characters (`\r`), but nothing is received.
This happens mostly after supplying the password to ssh.
I think it may be related to [this problem](https://askubuntu.com/a/401569/5698) - that for some NAT routers, ssh hang because that it sets the TOS field of the IP packets, immediately after authenticating the user.
This is the (level 3) debug output of ssh:

```
root@1.2.3.4 's password: 
debug3: packet_send2: adding 64 (len 55 padlen 9 extra_pad 64)

debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply

pa$$w0rd

debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).

Authenticated to 1.2.3.4  ([1.2.3.4]:22).

debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]

debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0

debug2: channel 0: send open

debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com

debug1: Entering interactive session.

debug2: callback start
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x10
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
```

Comment: Did you edit the expect script in a Windows text editor? It might have DOS-style line endings.

Comment: @glennjackman: Yes, using Notepad++. I don't think it happened, but will check (gonna take some time though)

Comment: You don't show your expect code: when you send a command, do you remember to "hit enter"? `exp_send "$cmd\r"`

Comment: @glennjackman: Sorry but the expect code is part of the framework and it is too complicated to copy-paste it properly (also I'm not allowed to do so). This is the reason that I'm looking for all the possible reasons to this problem. And yes - I "hit enter" (means `\r`) every time that I send a command. Thank you.

Comment: turn on debug output: `exp_internal 1` -- that should tell you why you are hitting timeout or your patterns don't match

Comment: Also, http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @glennjackman: Hi plz see my edit... added debug output of expect.